# How to solve"Error:Could not download hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3): No cached version available for offline mode"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, hamcrest

After I installed Android studio and started a simple project. There is an error as `" Error:Could not download hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3): No cached version available for offline mode".` I copied the sdk and gradle folder from my other computer because this computer has no internet connection. I also downloaded hamcrest-1.3 jar and unzipped it but I don't know how to resolv it.

The event log shows as that `"Gradle sync failed: Could not download hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3): No cached version available for offline mode Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"`
Finally, I connected the computer to Internet, I set the http proxy in Android studio then checked connection to google and the result is ok.

But the error is still existed. I am a new learner of android and ask for your patience.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow, when you have a minute please check up this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thank you

Comment: Show your gradle.properties so we can see the dependencies. It looks like you are asking Gradle to resolve dependencies, but if you don't have network access this will take some custom setup.

Answer (score -1):

Go to gradle.properties and comment all systemProp proxys and resync

its work for me

```
Android 2.3.3
```